# Flutter keeps in "Flutter Setup: Running pub upgrade" forever

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I recently changed some things in my project ( not in the pubspec.yaml file until then ) and since then, everytime I open the project, a message pops up in the bottom right corner saying "Flutter Setup: Running pub upgrade ".

I tried: 
    Installing dart and flutter extentions new.
    Reinstalling VS-Code
    Delete the Versions next to the dependencies and re-adding                       the newest version of each package.

To reproduce:

clone "https://github.com/IfClause/info_app_project.git" and open in VS-Code.

Thanks!

Output of 'flutter pub upgrade':

```
Running pub upgrade...
Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (8 tries left)
Running pub upgrade...
Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (7 tries left)
Running pub upgrade...
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are some mysterious issues with Flutter's cache.

If it is the case, `flutter clean && flutter doctor` should do it for you.

Also, it can happen to people with poor connections or behind firewalls.

Comment: I tried both commands, but the only thing I got is the same error as in the question.